# Set session attribute that is readable from external

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Oracle it is possible from PLSQL to set an attribute (`CLIENT_INFO`) in the session. This allows it to make the link between the session object and the running package/stored procedure. The package to do this is the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` package

So executing in the *client* session:

```
exec DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('hello stackoverflow');
```

allows it to see in an *admin* session view :

```
select sid, logon_time, client_info 
from v$session 
where client_info like '%stack%' ;

       SID LOGON_TIME          CLIENT_INFO
---------- ------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
      2549 2022-10-13 20:39:42 hello stackoverflow
```

Is there something equivalent for SQL Server that can be used via T-SQL?

Comment: `sp_set_session_context` maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 You can access it using `SESSION_CONTEXT()` function

Comment: @Charlieface There doesn't appear to be a means to access a `SESSION_CONTEXT()` for a _different_ session.

Comment: @HABO So it appears, which is surprising. DavidBrowne's code does not work with that, only with `CONTEXT_INFO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in SQL Server would be:

```
declare @ctx varbinary(128) = cast( 'hello stackoverflow' as varbinary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO  @ctx 
go
select s.session_id, connect_time, cast(context_info as varchar(128)) context_info
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
join sys.dm_exec_connections c
  on s.session_id = c.session_id 
where cast(context_info as varchar(128)) like '%stack%'
```

Comment: Hmm is there no way to get the newer `SESSION_CONTEXT` for a different session?

Comment: I don't believe there is any DMV that exposes the SESSION_CONTEXT values for other sessions.  You can, of course, write this data into a table.